# Cocoa magic? Where is my XIB being loaded?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to understand how Cocoa does its thing. The Cocoa Template's App Delegate file is this:

```
#import "Dataminer_ClientAppDelegate.h"

@implementation Dataminer_ClientAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 
}

@end
```

I see no reference do the MainMenu.xib anywhere, just an the window IBOutlet.

Looking at main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

This guy - NSApplicationMain - must be doing some magic. Is this documented somewhere?

Is there any way to disable all that and let me do things from scratch? (ie: load the XIB myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the best material I've found on this subject is here:

- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/demystifying-nsapplication-by.html
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/cocoa-application-startup.html

The first link goes so far as to try and recreate what `NSApplicationMain()` is doing under the hood.

Comment: Also, one could point out that NSApplicationMain will load the NSMainNibFile specified in your application's Info.plist.